# After upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 Ubuntu doesn't load the splash screen anymore

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, plymouth

I have the problem that Ubuntu doesn't load the splash screen anymore (after upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04). After the Grub-bootloader, it takes a few seconds to load and then the monitor turns black.

I already tried to boot from a Ubuntu Live CD, but the result was the same error. Furthermore I tried to start the protected mode, but it freezes just after showing me menu.

Do you have any solutions for this? 
And is it possible to switch from Grub to the Ubuntu console?

Comment: Do you ever get to GDM (login screen)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never get to GDM

Comment: Do you know what video card/chipset your using? How far into the Live-CD does it turn black? Can you make it to the menu that let's you choose to install or try?

Comment: My video card is a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250. My Chipset is a 64 Bit CPU (AMD Athlon II P320 Dual-Core). When I boot from the live cd I get just like my 'normal' boot to the four dots and the above standing ubuntu sign and then the monitor turns black. Therefore I can't make it the to menu of the live cd. If neccessary, I am able to boot from another live cd and make changes in configs.

Comment: If you can boot another Live CD then mount your Ubuntu partition and go into /etc/X11/ and rename xorg.conf to xorg.conf.back

Comment: I did the above yesterday. But unfornunately the result was the same. After I tried to boot I checked the directory /etc/X11/, but there hasn't been created a new xorg.conf. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution on the web.
For the HP 625 you have to turn off WLAN and Bluetooth. Then Ubuntu should boot. Then you need to uninstall "bcmwl-kernel-source" and every package containing "broadcom" drivers. Then reboot. And finally you turn on WLAN and Bluetooth again and install the drivers.

Comment: Yay! If you could mark this as the accepted answer (more on that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)) that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I see on the wiki is [Problem: Need to fully remove -fglrx and reinstall -ati from scratch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a%20%20Need%20to%20fully%20remove%20-fglrx%20and%20reinstall%20-ati%20from%20scratch)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But unfortunately I cannot get to a console of my Ubuntu Installation and the file /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh ain't existing in my directory.